# Embed Tag in Internet Explorer not working

Tags: sharepoint, video

I am developing a publishing portal in SharePoint. I have embedded a video in my page using the traditional embed tag inside the object tag. It works fine in Firefox. But, the video is not at all rendered in IE. I have IE 8 in my machine.

Is there any other way to add video in my page which is compatible with all the renowned browsers? I don't want to use any of the third party controls here. Any insights?

Regards,
Raghuraman.V

Comment: I would be surprised if this has anything to do with SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so that we cover all posibilities have you tried adding a Content Editor Web Part, then inserting the object to that web parts source code option? If that doesn't work, there is probably something wrong wtih your object tag!

Answer (score 0):

**embed** tag is for Mozilla only, you should use **object** tag for IE

Comment: Yes, that is the reason why I have used the embed tag inside the object tag